# What types (configurations) of dependencies are available out of the box in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I want to write a Gradle script to download a JAR file from Maven and combine it with some other resources to create an RPM file using the [`nebula.ospackage`](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin) plugin.

I can't declare the dependency using the `compile` configuration as it is not available without using the `java` plugin (and it also doesn't make sense to use `compile` as I am not compiling anything).

Is there a type of dependency I can use for this purpose?

Or am I required to use the `java` plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood `java` plugin will not be required. Please have a look a the script below - you can define custom configuration and use it in build script. As you can see, `java` plugin is not applied:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  lol
}

dependencies {
  lol 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task cp(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.lol
  into ('lol')
}
```